# Puppeteer - Async function in evaluate method throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to check if `og:image` source exists. If I want to call async method in [evaluate](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) function, I get `Error: Evaluation failed: [object Object]` error.

```
    Error: Evaluation failed: [object Object]
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:48:12)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.evaluate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:827:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at run (/Users/andrejgajdos/devel/link-preview/app.js:195:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

**app.sj**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const util = require('util');
const urlExists = util.promisify(require('url-exists'));

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.onepeloton.com/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

    const img = await page.evaluate(async () => {
      const ogImg = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
      if (ogImg != null && ogImg.content.length > 0) {
        const isExists = await urlExists(ogImg.content);
        return isExists;
      }
    });
    console.log(img);

    await browser.close()
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the code inside the `evaluate` is executed on the chromium side.
As `urlExists` is being imported on the node side, you **wouldn't** be able to access to that function from the browser.

**Unless** you expose it using [page.exposeFunction](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction). Once you expose that function, chromium will be able to call `urlExists`.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.onepeloton.com/', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
await page.exposeFunction('urlExists', urlExists);

const img = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const ogImg = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
    if (ogImg != null && ogImg.content.length > 0) {
    const isExists = await urlExists(ogImg.content);
    return isExists;
    }
});
console.log(img);

await browser.close()
```

Comment: Manu thanks, @hardkoded, for letting me know page.exposeFunction. You just saved me a lot of time.